# Trying to serialize

Tags: php, jquery

```
 <div class="signup">
          <div class="popover-markup" >
            <span  class="trigger">
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm register" role="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Register </a></br>
             </span>

            <div class="content hide content2" id="reg">
               <form class="form-horizontal" id="formRegister" action="#" >
               <div class="form-group form-group-md form-pic">

                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
              </span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group  ">

                <div class="col-sm-12">
                 <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" required placeholder="Enter name">
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                 <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
                  <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="Email address">
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group " >
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                 <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
                  <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" required placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <button type="submit" onclick="registration()" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm register_in_button"> <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Register </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want to serialize this form in jquery but it doesn't show any values, this is my jquery code

```
var form = $('div.content2 #formRegister').serialize();
```

what do i do wrong, can someone help me please?!

Comment: `var form = $('#formRegister').serialize();` and also show us full code of jquery and php to so that we can tell if any other problem exist

Comment: I recommend you append the output of `console.log($('div.content2 #formRegister')` and `console.log(form)` to this question (though I doubt either of these are the issue, so share more code as Anant suggests)

Comment: @Anant sure that would be preferred, but based on the html provided seems unlikely to be the issue. Also, as you say, we need more info

Comment: `var form = $('div.content2 #formRegister').serialize();` this is working. You have error in other section. please share full code.

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged as PHP since it's jquery / javascript only.

Comment: @xtreamwayz for all we know OP is using PHP without showing us that code

Comment: @Assimilaterah ok thanx, was just wondering for possible reasons.

Answer (score 1):

It works charming for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").text($("form").serialize());
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="signup">
          <div class="popover-markup" >
            <span  class="trigger">
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm register" role="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Register </a></br>
             </span>

            <div class="content hide content2" id="reg">
               <form class="form-horizontal" id="formRegister" action="#" >
               <div class="form-group form-group-md form-pic">

                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
              </span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group  ">

                <div class="col-sm-12">
                 <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" required placeholder="Enter name">
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                 <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
                  <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="Email address">
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group " >
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                 <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
                  <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" required placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <button type="submit" onclick="registration()" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm register_in_button"> <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Register </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple You can use,**

```
$(selector).serialize()//function
$(".signup").serialize();
```

Comment: Is this answer really adding anything to what the OP has already done?

Comment: still not working i don't know why but this is my jquery code